# Call stored procedures of postgresql using node js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, stored-procedures

How can I call the stored procedures from postgresql in nodejs using async await.

This is my pool.

```
const pool = new pg.Pool({
user: "postgres",
password: "password",
host: "localhost",
database: "mydatabase",
port: 5432
});
```

This is  the code.

```
app.put("/:id", async(req, res) => {
try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { name, email, hobby } = req.body;
    const updateStudent = await pool.proc('updateUser', [name, email, hobby, id]);
    res.json("Student was updated")
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
}
})
```